# get date and display in a lable? And how can i convert it to a string(date)

Tags: java, string, date, getdate, jdatechooser

I want this date which have picked form jdateChooser to converted into string and displayed init jlable

```
java.util.Date date = jDateChooser1.getDate();
date.toInstant();
jLabel16.setText(date);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `toString()` method, it converts an object to a String, do this `jLabel16.setText(date.toString());` to display the contents of the object in the label.